# update the result of select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, regex

I have managed to create a join select statement

```
SELECT l.rank, r.rank
        FROM (SELECT * FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE newurl REGEXP 'Itemid\=108' AND rank<>0 GROUP BY oldurl HAVING MAX(id)) AS l
            JOIN (SELECT * FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE rank=0 GROUP BY oldurl) AS r
                ON l.oldurl=r.oldurl;
```

What I need is to swap ranks around. Another words `UPDATE` that each time `l.rank` would become `r.rank` and `r.rank` would become `l.rank`.

If for example in first row the result of first select is 0 and second select 2. I want that after update it would be another way around and first would be 2 and second 0.

I hope it makes any sense.

Comment: mysql or sqlserver ? Both are different.

Comment: Are you trying to have 0 return in your results, or are you actually trying to update the table?

Comment: I am trying to determine the links, which contains Itemid\=108 for each group of duplicates and rank the link with the highest id as 0. So if there are two links, containing Itemid\=108 within one group and having ids 3 and 5. I want to rank the one with id 5 as 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but is this it?  YOu don't want a "Select *" on the select statement in the update, but a select ID.  Then you will have a list of IDs that you want to update from.  What I did was fix up the update syntax (assuming MS-SQL) and give a list of ids only to look at.  I left your select criteria alone, assuming that you've already got that right.  :)

`Set Rank = 0 where id in 
(SELECT id FROM as795_sh404sef_urls 
WHERE newurl REGEXP 'Itemid\=108' AND rank<>0 AND oldurl='zumba-gold-8.html' GROUP BY oldurl HAVING MAX(id))`

Comment: UPDATE as795_sh404sef_urls SET rank = 0 WHERE oldurl='karate-classes-for-all-93.html' AND id IN (SELECT id FROM(SELECT id FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE newurl REGEXP 'Itemid\=108' AND rank<>0 GROUP BY oldurl,id HAVING MAX(id))AS T);

But for some reason it updates the second max(id). Another words if there are two links, which contain Itemid\=108, one of them have id 5, and another one 4. Instead of setting 0 rank for 5 it sets it for 4. Could you advise me why?